# FPS measurement

Tags: performance, frame-rate

I want to calculate FPS to keep track od my application performance. I have read about two ways of doing it: calculating number of frames generated and measuring frame duration and then dividing a second by this value to get average calculation. Which way is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

Choosing of method depend on a goal. If the goal is to estimate performance, then may be more reasonable just measuring total time and total number of frames of a very specific preprogrammed sequence.

When the FPS meter used as an info for the user, then FPS info should not be updated too fast, but periodically.

Things depend on how accurate the timer is. Let's say we have timer with 1ms accuracy, and 60FPS frame rate. Therefore each frame will be 16-17 ms, providing an 6% error. 
This may be useful to log the information to find out if some particular frames slow down the FPS, while average FPS will remain relatively high, but if displaying information to the user, so high speed of update will not be informative.

If the frame rate is calculated by counting integer number of frames over constant period of time, then cons are: slow FPS information update and impossible to measure fractional FPS. Decreasing period of FPS meter update will also decrease it's accuracy.

Counting duration of some predefined number of frames may solve the problem, but will decrease update rate if FPS drops down.

I often use a combined method to display FPS:
1) Remember the start time
2) Display frames and increase counter until
3) If time elapsed since start time more than arbitrary threshold (for example 0.5 seconds), then calculate FPS = [number of frames] / [elapsed time]. Current time then become a new [start time]